# Calculate LifePo4 optimal charging current

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, lifepo4

How do I work out the optimum charging amps for a LFP 2P4S battery?

I have 8 x 66 Ah Sinopoly cells.
http://www.sinopolybattery.com/userfiles/files/SP-LFP66AHA.pdf

Charge Specs

- Standard Current 22A CC&CV
- Max. Current 132 A 2 C
- Limited Voltage 3.65 V
- Cut-off Current 2.18 A 0.033 C

As I have 2P4S making 132 Ah is the max current 132 Ah x 2 C = 264 A?

Is the "standard current" the optimal charging? Is it now double to 44 A?

Comment: (The question is not *everything to consider about charging LiFePO*.) How fast do you need charging to be? Anywhere from 2*4 A (2*Cut-off) to **1** *125 A (doesn't of itself damage one series connection should the other one go disconnected) that's trusty and fast enough, and you feel a good value for money. About 17 A/600 W for "overnight" (8h) charging. Expect reduced cycle count above 2*22 A.

Answer (score 0):

Not that simple. For "optimal results" each battery should be charged sort-of individually, aka with "balanced charger". You can't just sum up the charging current for the 2P connection, because each battery have different internal resistance, and will charge (and discharge) to a different SOC (State Of Charge). As result, the batteries won't be charged "optimally" at least, and at most will self-drain faster.

Regarding the current, it looks that you can charge the cells at any current up to 132 A (2C), just the number of work cycles will likely do down with 2C charging. Their "22 A" number is likely the optimal value.

Similar considerations apply to 4S (serial) connection: time to reach the terminal voltage (aka "limited voltage") will be likely different for each cell. The charger must balance this difference.

In sum, just "summing" charging currents doesn't work well, and definitely can't be called as "optimal".

Comment: All that, plus I wouldn't trust the parallel strings to absorb the same amount of current.  If I didn't control the *current* to each string individually, I'd make sure to keep it well below that 132A figure.

Comment: They *won't* take equal current, but they *will* equalize to essentially identical state-of-charge, despite differences in internal resistance or even capacity. Balance charging is a must-have for series strings, not really for parallel, if you take care to avoid over-current.